# How to use Immutable Objects with SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-pcl

I keep getting the following error when trying to initialize my [SQLite-NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) database:

> Cannot create a table without columns (does 'PersonModel' have public properties?)

I have a class `PersonModel` that I want to be immutable, however SQLite is telling me that `PersonModel` must be mutable, e.g. each property must use `public set;`.

How can I continue using [SQLite-NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) with immutable properties?

```cs
class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; } //Read-only Property, cannot be changed after initialization
    public string LastName { get; } //Read-only Property, cannot be changed after initialization
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

That error is happening because SQLite-NET uses [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection?WT.mc_id=mobile-10939-bramin) to initialize the objects it retrieves from our database, and Reflection requires `public set;` to initialize each property.

### Answer

We can take advantage of [Init-Only Setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init?WT.mc_id=mobile-10939-bramin), new in [C# 9.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/?WT.mc_id=mobile-10939-bramin).

Init-Only Setters allow us to define properties that can be set during initialization, AND cannot be changed. In other words init-only setters let us create immutable objects, AND they allow Reflection to create Immutable Objects!

I go deeper into this topic in this blog post: https://codetraveler.io/2020/11/11/using-immutable-objects-with-sqlite-net/

### Code

Remove the constructor on `Person` (Reflection requires a parameterless constructor), and implement init-only setters for each property:

```cs
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; } //Read-only Property, can be set during initialization, but cannot be changed after initialization
    public string LastName { get; init; } //Read-only Property, can be set during initialization, but cannot be changed after initialization
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a `PersonDto` class that does all of the SQLite interactions:

```
class PersonDto
{
    
    public PersonDto(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then the `Person` class encapsulates the DTO object:

```
class Person
{
    private PersonDto _dto;
    
    public Person(PersonDto dto)
    {
        this._dto = dto;
    }

    public string FirstName => _dto.FirstName;
    public string LastName => _dto.LastName;
}
```